# Clustering of liquid fueled rocket engines

Tags: rockets, history, stages, cluster

Which rocket first used clustering of liquid fueled rocket engines on their first stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a few different candidates depending on your definitions.

1946: The [Bell X-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_X-1) rocket plane used the [XLR-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_Motors_XLR11), a 4-chamber, pressure-fed rocket engine using liquid propellants. The four chambers were integrated into a single module, so it should probably be considered a single engine rather than a cluster, but the four chambers could be individually turned on and off. In theory the X-1 could take off from a runway, but in practice it was always dropped from a B-29 mothership, so it's also debatable whether this counts as a first stage.

1957: The [R-7 ICBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-7_Semyorka) used the [RD-107/RD-108 engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-107) on its four boosters and core stage. This is an engine with four combustion chambers, but driven by a common turbopump, which by convention is considered a single engine, so it's not technically a cluster. If you consider the four individual boosters as a single stage, that would be a four-engine cluster.

1961: The [Saturn I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_I) used a cluster of 8 [H-1 engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_H-1) on its first stage (and a cluster of 6 [RL10 engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL10) on the second stage). This is the earliest unambiguous example of a liquid-propellant clustered first stage I could find.

There are probably other experimental examples of clustered engines. The [Wikipedia article on Robert Goddard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_H._Goddard#Annapolis,_Maryland) mentions a "3000-lb thrust engine using a cluster of four 750-lb thrust motors" built at Caltech; this would have been in the late '40s or early '50s, but I can't find any more information on it, so I don't know if it was ever associated with a particular rocket stage.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, in case of twin chamber engines like the LR 87, how did they ensure equal propellant supply to both chambers? Did they use any flow dividers?